# Neo4J exclude nodes after set property

Tags: neo4j

I have only just started with Neo4j so I suspect I am missing something very basic here.  Given I have the following graph.

[image]

And starting on the highlighted node (ID 7937) I need to get all the connected nodes but nothing passed any of the "off" nodes.

Using this

```
match (n:TestNode)-[:LINK*]-(m) 
where ID(n) = 7937
return *
```

Gives me everything of course which I would suspect due to no filter.

I need the end result to be:

[image]

This seems to give me the result I need.  Is this the correct way or something better:

```
match p=n-[:LINK*..]-m
   where ID(n) = 7937 and all(x in nodes(p) WHERE x.status = 'on') 
return p;
```

Comment: Your way is the correct one, because what you want is a path containing only "on" nodes, and stopping at the first "off" node, or not stopping at all (if you don't have any "off" node in your path) if I'm right.

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not give you the results you said you wanted. That is, it does not include the nearest `off` nodes in the results.

Here is a query that does include the nearest `off` nodes. However, the results will contain partial paths as well as full paths; this is because your data has no consistent directionality to the `LINK` relationships, so it is hard to determine when we have reached the end of a path (it can probably be done, but it would make the query more complex).

```
MATCH p=n-[:LINK*..]-m
WHERE ID(n) = 7937
RETURN DISTINCT REDUCE(s =[n], x IN NODES(p)[1..] |
  CASE (s[-1]).status
    WHEN 'on' THEN s + x
    ELSE s
  END) AS res;
```

Here is [a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=akgyee) that shows sample results.

Comment: Thanks.  Good to know how to include the off nodes.